# How to issue file permission on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, file-sharing, opendocument

Perhaps I'm on the wrong approach, however here is what I'm trying to do on AWS: I have a collection of OpenDocument files (calc, base) and I need to share those to other people; each user should access **an instance** of the file, meaning he/she can use its functionalities but not modify and more importanty he/she cannot **download** the file.

I tried setting up permission using the AWS policy generator, but once the file is accessible it can be modified and/or downloaded.

Is there a more simple solution for this?

Comment: How will your users 'use' the files? Do they run software on their own computer, or in a web browser?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein my files are OpenDocuments so for what I could understand AWS do support those with browser, for calc the can entr values in unlocked cells, the core part is allowing them to save an instance (a copy) of the modified file in the server to access it in future. Same goes for base files, where they can only query the data using a form.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but how does a user access an OpenDocument? Do they connect to an app on a web server (like Google Docs)? If so, where is this running (on an EC2 instance you provide)? Or do they run the software on their own computer like Microsoft Excel?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein for what I read on AWS they allow to open certain documents via user browser (maybe they use some applet, Im not sure how they do) much like when you preview a PDF file, this is how I got it from their docs.

Answer (score 2):

If you deal with files, users will be able to download or access. So, You should be looking at a VM/VDI solution to enable them to only 'Use' but not download or copy.

eg: AWS has [App Streaming](https://aws.amazon.com/appstream2/) which I think serves your use case.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the right direction on AWS, since I cannot control the user behavior, should they leave an instance open 24h/day will cost too much, unless it is possible to limit the hours a user can access it every month. I need to read about this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to: [New Collaborative Editing for Amazon WorkDocs – Powered by Hancom Thinkfree Office Online | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-collaborative-editing-for-amazon-workdocs-powered-by-hancom-thinkfree-office-online/)

There does appear to be a permission in Amazon WorkDocs that can prevent downloading of files. See: [Permissions - Amazon WorkDocs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workdocs/latest/userguide/permissions.html)

You can also limit users to have **View only** permissions.

[Amazon WorkDocs costs](https://aws.amazon.com/workdocs/pricing/) $5 per user per month.

See: [What Is Amazon WorkDocs?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workdocs/latest/userguide/what_is.html)